# How do I update properties on a shopify line_item

Tags: api, shopify

How do I update the properties for a specific line_item using the shopify api?

There does not seem to be a method to directly update a specific line item.

I then tried to update the entire order object instead, but it seems like it is not saving my properties. If I save the order with the following json, the api returns the full order object, but with an empty properties [] line for my line_items.

```
{"order":{"id":94202342,"line_items":[{"id":615546756,"variant_id":627937216,"properties":[{"my_test_key":"This_is_a_test"}]}]}}
```

Comment: From Shopify docs: `Change an order’s attributes such as note, email, buyer-accepts-marketing, or remove the customer association`. I'm afraid you can't change anything else in an order.

Comment: The phrase "such as" should indicate that it is just examples of what you can change. Not the entire list.

Comment: You can check their documentation on orders API at https://docs.shopify.com/api/reference/order and correct me in my statement. I'll be happy to know if it succeeds.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can *create a new order* with the API but you can't update the line items of an existing order.

From the [Order API docs](https://docs.shopify.com/api/reference/order):

> You should also note that you can change only a few of an order's
>   attributes using the API. **You cannot change the items or the
>   quantities in an order.**

Comment: Just to clarify: Are you 100% sure that adding a comment to an item is "Changing the item?". The "Or the quantities" makes it sound like you just can't add/remove items.

Comment: @MTilsted.. I'm not sure why you'd want to add/remove items from an order already placed?

Comment: I don't. What I want is to modify the comment for some line_items within an order.

Comment: @MTilsted well I haven't tested it, but it sounds like you have, and it didn't work, so that would support my interpretation of the docs. Could you accomplish the same goal by adding note_attribute records to the Order, where each attribute name identifies the line item that the data is for?