# How do I use shopify to sell third party product which need to be shown in the customers account page

Tags: shopify

Some of the products we sell in our Shopify shop are third party downloads, which we resell.

So when a customer buys such a product in our shop, it activate a webhook once the order is paid. This webhook then order the product from the third party. This third party gives us a download link which we then email to the customer.

This works fine, but we would also like to show the download link at the customers account page, so they can log in, and then re-download any file they have previously bought. And here is the problem: How do we store the download links for each product, in a way we can show at the users account page?

The obvious solution would be to store the unique download link in the orders line_item but that is not supported by shopify([How do I update properties on a shopify line_item](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36351913/how-do-i-update-properties-on-a-shopify-line-item)).

Comment: If the download links provided by the third party are not dynamic and are static link, a simpler solution to @bknights solution is possible.

Comment: They are unique, for each user. But once generated for a specific "user+file" combination, they don't change.

Comment: Then you should follow @bknights solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd use a meta field on the order. You could create a set of metafields from the order webhook to handle all the download links and then modify your theme to show them.

Comment: Yea. I think it'll answer his other question as well.